# CSS: Select label and change color, if sibling input has no value

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to make all `labels` have `color: red;` if their `sibling` `input` has **no** `value`.

I try to select first the `inputs` **without** a `value` like this:

```
.state-input--red > .input__wrapper > .input__input:not([value])
```

And after that I'm trying to select his `sibling` `label` adding this part:

```
~ .input__label
```

So I got this selection and setting `color` to `red`, but it doesn't work:

```
.state-input--red > .input__wrapper > .input__input:not([value]) ~ .input__label {
  color: red;
}
```

I also tried to specify the `sibling` selection by adding also the `.input__wrapper >` before the `label`, but it doesn't work. Here is my snippet:

```css
.state-input--red > .input__wrapper > .input__input:not([value]) ~ .input__label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="input state-input--red">
  <div class="input__wrapper">
    <label class="input__label" for="input00">I should be black, because my siblin input has a value</label>
    <input id="input00" type="text" value="Hello World">
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="input state-input--red">
  <div class="input__wrapper">
    <label class="input__label" for="input01">I should be red, because my sibling input has no value</label>
    <input id="input01" class="input__input" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A selector like `a ~ b` matches all the siblings `b` elements preceded by an `a` element, but in your markup the it's instead the `label` who precedes the `input`: that's the reason why it doesn't work.

As a possible solution you could turn your `.input__wrapper` element into a `flexbox` container with `flex-direction: row-reverse`, then switch the order of `label` and `input` in the code to keep the current visualization.

Doing so a selector like `.input__input:not([value]) ~ .input__label` will work as expected.

Comment: So basically, my css selector would work, if the order of the elements in the markup would be reversed?

Comment: @MrBuggy exactly: the general sibling combinator (~) and the adjacent sibling combinator (+) only work for the following sibling/s.

Comment: Or you could use the `order` property to explicitly reorder the visual display of the elements or, with CSS Grid, use named `grid-area`s.

Comment: Nice on, it works with the flexbox solution, awesome! I though that the (+) selector looks on the order of the elements and the (~) on the adjacent siblings, but no mather wich direction. Thanks for this!